# Create database in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've inherited a Symfony project that uses a MySQL DB.  I need to create a second database.  I've changed the …/htdocs/projectFolder/app/config/parameters.yml to have a new dbName.

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 8889
    database_name: inherited_db_name
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: nosecret
    database_path: null
```

Changed to:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1 #can't use "localhost"
    database_port: 8889
    database_name: new_db_to_create
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: nosecret
    database_path: null
```

I have tried all the tricks I can thing of but the command: 
`doctrine:database:create` just keeps trying to create “inherited_db_name”

If I drop the “inherited_db_name” DB and then run the command again w/ the new parameters.yml the “inherited_db_name” is recreated.  I've searched and grep-ed for the “inherited_db_name” but cannot find out where it's coming from.  ANY suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache before you run the command again?

Comment: I have run: console cache:clear and virtually all the other console cache command.  Still unable to gen new DB.

Comment: rm -r app/cache/dev will make sure the cache is completely cleared.

Comment: Silly question are you sure that you are running the command from the same symfony install. Meaning the parameters.yml that you changed is in the same sub dir from where you are running the command?

Comment: As per @Cerad the rm -r .../dev worked. Also skrilled insight helped point in this direction.  Chausser: good question thanks.

Comment: Good - sometimes you just gotta use a nuke.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your Symfony2 application to manage both databases.

So your *parameters.yml* file will look like:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 8889
    database_name: inherited_db_name
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    database_driver2: pdo_mysql
    database_host2: 127.0.0.1 #can't use "localhost"
    database_port2: 8889
    database_name2: new_db_to_create
    database_user2: root
    database_password2: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: nosecret
    database_path: null
```

Now you just need to configure Doctrine properly:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   "%database_driver2%"
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle:  ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    AcmeCustomerBundle: ~
```

Please take a look to the Symfony2 cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html